# Problems using the ScrollToAsync() method from ScrollView in the OnAppearing() of a Content Page

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, async-await

I have in my code behind file made an override to the OnAppearing() method, to do some automatic scrolling to a specific element which is a child inside my ScrollView element in my XAML file. I use the method `ScrollToAsync()` from the ScrollView element, to Scroll to the element MyBox, which is a BoxView element.

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    await HorizontalScrollView.ScrollToAsync(MyBox, ScrollToPosition.Center, false);
    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

My Problem is here that when the page appear it doesnt scroll to the MyBox element automatically. However I got it to work if I inserted a `Task.Delay()`.

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(1);
    await HorizontalScrollView.ScrollToAsync(MyBox, ScrollToPosition.Center, false);
    base.OnAppearing();
}
```

My question is why it works, when I insert the delay, and is there any way I can get rid of using the `Task.Delay()` statement?

Comment: Try to invoke the line after  `base.OnAppearing();` .

Comment: It did not change anything

Comment: Yes, the answer you gave me worked. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke the line in UIThread (Main Thread) like following

```
protected override async void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async ()=> {
        await HorizontalScrollView.ScrollToAsync(MyBox, ScrollToPosition.Center, false);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Device" is deprecated. Now you need to use this:

```
MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(...
```